# iCloud Not Showing Files On Mac, Not working

Tags: icloud

I logged out of iCloud on my Mac, and all my desktop items were deleted. I was Able to restore them, but now my iCloud Drive files are not showing in my finder:

[image]

Even stranger still, when I try to drag and drop something from my iCloud Drive to my desktop, it appears as a file called (Data), no matter what it is:

[image]

I've rebooted my computer, turned iCloud Drive off and on, turned off documents in iCloudDrive options. Nothing has worked. Here are my settings:

[image: User Preference Settings]

I've tried everything, I have 6 months worth of work that I can't really access. I can manually download things from iCloud Drive, but not files. One project of mine has 1,200 files In it, so cant really take that route.

Any help would be appreciated.

This is what my desktop should look like:
[image]

Comment: What is set in the individual settings in Options… ?

Comment: Everything in it is checked on, including the files and documents option

Comment: For now, I’ve turned on optimize Mac storage, and have my computer set to not fall asleep. Although highly unlikely, I’m hoping that leaving it on will give it time to sync after this most recent reboot. However, I’m pretty sure waiting it out like this isn’t going to be a solution.

Comment: When you sign out of iCloud, all synced content is removed from that device.  That's done by design.  It can several hours to a few days for content to sync back from iCloud to your device.  How long have you been waiting?

Comment: That’s what I had heard, and I originally waited around 36 hours while preventing my laptop to sleep. However, from researching it, I’ve found that it shouldn’t take more than 24 hours max for the less than 1 gig of data stored. What really peaked my worries was the fact that everything from iCloud dragged in gets put as ‘Data’, an unkown file type that I can’t do anything with. That, and the files weren’t just ‘removed’, it was deleted from my account altogether. I had to restore it so that I could have the files back on my iCloud. In the past, data never was deleted off of my iCloud as well.